# What is the status of apt-get relative to apt?

Tags: 16.04, apt

I use `apt` for update, full-upgrade, and to install, remove, and purge. Sometimes I use autoremove but it is probably unnecessary because I am not lacking disk space. I do not recall ever needing to use `apt-get` since I became aware of `apt`.

Has `apt` made `apt-get` unnecessary for the vast majority of users?

Comment: Yep, the vast majority of us users don't need the extra features that still exist only in `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Has apt made apt-get unnecessary for the vast majority of users?* Short answer: yes. The `apt` command substitutes for `apt-get` and more.

Ubuntu is based on Debian, and as such also uses the Advanced Package Tool (APT, do not confuse with the `apt` command). This involves a variety of tools to interact with APT for installing, remove and managing software. These tools are partly integrated in higher-level tools for easier use. `apt-get` and `aptitude` are such tools. Next to `apt-get`, there are several other tools, including `apt-cache`, `apt-config`.

The more recent **`apt`** command is integrating core functionality for package management in one command, and aims to be a more user friendly command line tool for the end user.